# Entropy of two expanding and mixing ideal gases

Tags: thermodynamics, homework-and-exercises, entropy

I am currently stuck with the following problem:

```
 _________________________         _________________________
|                 |       |    \  |                         | 
|        V1       |   V2  | ====> |        V1+V2            |
|                 |       |    /  |                         |      
|_________________|_______|       |_________________________|
```

In a box there are two different gases in two compartments seperated by a solid wall. The Temperature $T$ of both gases is the same and both gases consist of $1mol$ particles. Therefore on the left side of the box, you have a volume of $V_1$ with a pressure of $p_1$ and on the right hand side we have volume $V_2$ and pressure $p_2$. No we remove the separating wall.

Lets first assume that we have to different gases on the left and on the right side. My goal is to calculate the change of entropy which occurs due to the removal of the wall. My first Ansatz was:

$\Delta S_1 = nR\ln(\frac{V_1+V_2}{V_1})$

$\Delta S_2 = nR\ln(\frac{V_1+V_2}{V_2})$

Where $\Delta S$ is the change of entropy of the system, $n$ the number of mols and $R$ the universal gas constant. The total change of entropy would now be the sum of both:

$\Delta S_{tot} = S_1 + S_2 = nR\ln(\frac{(V_1+V_2)^2}{V_1V_2})$

After a while I thought about the problem in a different way: First I move the wall isothermally so that $V_1=V_2$. The entropy change due to the movement would be:

$\Delta S_{mov1} = nR\ln(\frac{V_1+V_2}{2V_1})$

$\Delta S_{mov2} = nR\ln(\frac{V_1+V_2}{2V_2})$

$\Delta S_{mov} = S_{mov1} + S_{mov2} = nR\ln(\frac{(V_1+V_2)^2}{4V_1V_2})$

Now i remove the wall and get a entropy change due to the mixing of the gasses:

$\Delta S_{rem} = R(n_1 ln(\frac{n_1+n_2}{n_1}) + n_2 \ln(\frac{n_1+n_2}{n_2})) = 2nR\ln(2)$

so

$\Delta S_{tot} =  \Delta S_{rem} + \Delta S_{mov} =  nR\ln(\frac{(V_1+V_2)^2}{4V_1V_2}) + 2nR\ln(2)$

which is clearly different from the result I got from my approach in the first Ansatz. However since entropy is a state variable this should not happen. No I am stuck. I tend to the second result, but I am very far from sure. It would be great if you could explain which ansatz is correct (if any^^).

Moreover if I had identical gases in $V_1$ and $V_2$, how would the entropy behave? Since the pressure changes after the removal of the wall, I would say that the entropy also changes. Just like in my second Ansatz, however without the mixing term. Is this correct?

||~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

EDIT: Oh, dear. I just realized that $2nRln(2)$ can be written as $nRln(4)$. Therefore

$nR\ln(\frac{(V_1+V_2)^2}{4V_1V_2}) + 2nR\ln(2) = nR\ln(\frac{(V_1+V_2)^2}{V_1V_2})$

so both ansatzes give the same result. Since this is cleared out, my second question remains. In case of two identical gases does the entropy change according to my second ansatz (without the mixing entropy)?

Thanks in advance

ftiaronsem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've stumbled upon is called the "Gibbs paradox", and the resolution is to divide the phase space for entropy calculations in statistical mechanics by the identical particle factor, which reduces the number of configurations.

Since the temperature is unchanged in the process, the momentum distribution of the atoms is unimportant, it is the same before and after, and the entropy is entirely spatial, as you realized. The volume of configuration space for the left part is:

${V_1^N \over N!}$

and for the right part is:

${V_2^N\over N!}$

And the total volume of the 2N particle configuration space is:

$(V_1V_2)^N\over (N!)^2$

When you lift the barrier, you get the spatial volume of configuration space

$(V_1 + V_2)^{2N} \over (2N)!$

When $V_1$ and $V_2$ are equal, you naively would expect zero entropy gain. But you do gain a tiny little bit of entropy by removing the wall. Before you removed the wall, the number of particles on the left and on the right were exactly equal, now they can fluctuate a little bit. But this is a negligible amount of extra entropy in the thermodynamic limit, as you can see:

${(2V)^{2N}\over (2N)!} = {2^{2N}(N!)^2\over (2N)!}{V^{2N}\over (N!)^2}$

So that the extra entropy from lifting the barrier is equal to:

$ \log ({(2N)!\over 2^{2N}(N!)^2})$

You might recognize the thing inside the log, it's the probability that a symmetric +/-1 random walk returns to the origin after N steps, i.e. the biggest term of the Pascal triangle at stage 2N when normalized by the sum of all the terms of Pascal's triangle at that stage. From the Brownian motion identity or equivalently, directly from Stirling's formula), you can estimate its size as ${1\over \sqrt{2\pi N}}$, so that the logarithm goes as log(N), it is sub-extensive, and vanishes for large numbers.

The entropy change in the general case is then exactly given by the logarithm of the ratio of the two configuration space volumes before and after:

$e^{\Delta S} = { V_1^N V_2^N \over (N!)^2 } { (2N)! \over (V_1 + V_2)^{2N}} = { V_1^N V_2^N \over ({V_1 + V_2 \over 2})^{2N}} {(2N)!\over 2^{2N}(N!)^2}$

Ignoring the thermodynamically negligible last factor, the macroscopic change in entropy, the part proprtional to N, is:

$\Delta S = N\log({4 V_1 V_2 \over (V_1 + V_2)^2})$

up to a sign, it is as you calculated.

#### Additional comments

You might think that it is weird to gain a little bit of entropy just from the fact that before you lift the wall you knew that the particle numbers were exactly N, even if that entropy is subextensive. Wouldn't that mean that when you lower the wall, you reduce the entropy a tiny subextensive amount, by preventing mixing of the right and left half? Even if the entropy decrease is tiny, it still violates the second law.

There is no entropy decrease, because when you lower the barrier, you don't know how many molecules are on the left and how many are on the right. If you add the entropy of ignorance to the entropy of the lowered wall system, it exactly removes the subextensive entropy loss. If you try to find out how many molecules are on the right vs how many are on the left, you produce more entropy in the process of learning the answer than you gain from the knowledge.

Comment: What is your point? In a comment to my answer you said that in case of two identical gases, after mixing, the entropy of the system increases($\Delta S \neq0 $). So for example, if $V_1=V_2$ and $p_1 \neq  p_2$, what is $\Delta S$

Comment: The entropy gain for identical volumes and different numbers of molecules on either side is $\log 2|N_1-N_2|$, where N is determined from P by the ideal gas law. If $N_2=0$, if there is zero pressure on one side, the entropy gain is $N_1\log 2$.

Comment: Yes, i agree with this. But the OP question assumes that $N_1=N_2$ so that the answer to its second question about two identical gases is still $\Delta S =0$?

Comment: The OP question assumes that $N_1 = N_2$ but $V_1 \ne V_2$, then there is an entropy gain as described above. If $N_1=N_2$ and $V_1 = V_2$, then of course there is no extensive entropy gain. that's also true whenever ${N_1\over V_1} = {N_2\over V_2}$, i.e. when the pressures are equal. There is extensive entropy gain whenever the left box is different from the right box in any extensive quantity.

Comment: I still can not fully understand the treatment of your(it is too technical for me). If we have one gas in two compartments seperated by a solid wall then actually the volume of the gas does not change. Temperature of the gas also does not change. It is clear when we have 2 different gases. Then the volume of both gases will change. How do you calculate $\Delta S$ by using the definition:$ \Delta S=\int  \frac{\delta Q}{T}$

Comment: My treatment is using the statistical definition $S = log C$ where C is the volume of possible configurations. This definition is both more fundamental and easier to work with than the equivalent thermodynamic integral, and it gives correct subextensive entropy corrections. You can also calculate $\Delta S$ by imagining moving the wall slowly until the pressures are equal, and extracting work from the system. The heat flowing in equals the work done, to keep things at constant T. The integral of $\delta Q\over T$ reproduces the statistical answer.

Comment: I think, you've made ​​things too complicated. The physics is shadowed by the mathematics. One can easily get lost out there. The problem can be solved without any calculation, i think. In fact, the volume of the gas does not change and thus the gas as a whole does not perform  no work.  The internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on the temperature and the pressure difference doesn't matter. So the initial state and the final state are indistinguishable.  The entropy does not change($\Delta S=0$).

Comment: Absolutely false. If you lift a wall in a way that something irreversible happens, the entropy goes up. I know that it is possible to make a mistake, that's why I double checked. The mathematics in my answer is simpler than the mathematics in the question.

Comment: Irreversible? Were the loss or dissipation of energy?

Comment: When you lift a wall with two containers at different pressure, the gas at higher pressure does work, and the gas expands into the other.

Comment: Yes, but if you lift the wall back then you get the same amount of the work back.

Comment: @Martin: No you don't. If you _lift_ a wall, that means, open the door, the gas irreversibly does work. If you want to do it reversibly, you have to _slide_ the wall until the pressures are equal, and then _lift_ the wall.

Comment: Damn, I got the word "lift" wrong. Sorry for the confusion! But i do not see an irreversibility. The process is supposed to be isothermal. After the pressures are equal you can slide the wall in such a way that you get the initial state back. The temperature of the gas remains constant.

Comment: @Martin: but when you slide the wall, you do work. You can always reverse an irreversible change by doing work.

Comment: Yes, but I got the energy that is released after the lift of the wall. The amount of this energy is equal to the work i need to perform to bring the system back to its original state. Net result: system and surroundings(with me) back to the initial state. I.e. the process is reversible.

Comment: @Martin: No, No, No! You lift a wall with different pressures, the pressures equilibrate. You lower the wall, they don't separate. This is completely obvious!

Comment: After i lifted the wall i can slide it (quasi-statically) to any position. This is obviously a reversible action. Now, if i lower the wall i can slide it in such a way that the system reaches its original state.

Comment: @Martin: you don't understand reversibility. If you lift the wall when the gas is at equal pressure on either side, this is reversible. If you lift the wall when the gas is unequal pressure, this is not reversible. You can do some work to bring the gas back to unequal pressure, but this requires work. You _could have_ extracted the same amount of work by letting the gas do work instead of wasting the pressure difference by opening the wall, but _you didn't_. You wasted it. That's irreversible.

Comment: I have to say that your solution has confounded me. Yes, i don't understand the reversibility, in this specific problem. After some reflection, i think i finally got to fully understand what is really happening. Actually, there is nothing to reverse, i think. If you lift the wall, nothing happens, in the thermodynamic sense. Surroundings have received no work because the volume of the gas remains unchanged.  
There is no heat exchange with the surrounding(If we assume that the container is thermally insulated then the temp. of the gas will not change)...

Comment: ...That means the system stays on its original state and thus the entropy does not change.  We can think of the pressure difference inside the gas just as a random fluctuation. These fluctuations are irrelevant in this problem.

Comment: @Ron: Thanks for your very instructive answer. It has been a while since I last checked my stackexchange sites, otherwise I would have replied sooner.

Comment: @Ron: Regarding your answer, I have a few questions, regarding the methematics. I noticed you wrote ${(2V)^{2N}\over (2N)!^2} = {2^{2N}(N!)^2\over (2N)!}{V^{2N}\over (N!)^2}$, however the $(N!)^2$ are cancelling, resulting in a false identity. I tried to reconstruct the correct term, from $\log ({(2N)!\over 2^{2N}(N!)^2})$ which you have given as entropy. However I am failing to derive an identity.

Comment: @Ron: The second question I have is about you saying $\log ({(2N)!\over 2^{2N}(N!)^2})$ behaves as log(N). I believe that, but for large amount particles log(N) does not vanish. Did you mean it becomes small in comparison to other entropy effects? In anyway huge thanks to you for this very good answer. I knew that an entropy change due to an information change exists, however I never had an example for it. This is really great

Comment: @Martin: Certainly Ron is the more competent answerer to your questions, but I believe you should consider that the temperature can and will change locally after I lift the wall. (@Ron: Pleaese correct me if I am wrong) As one gas expands into the other one, the first one will cool down locally (just in small areas), while the other locally heats up. During the process in which the pressure equilibrium is reached, the resulting heat difference is also equalized. But since temperature is equalized, heat is flowing. And heatflow is always irreversible.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Regarding the mathematical question--- the N! cancel, and the 1/(2N)! are the same on both sides, and this leaves the true identity: $(2V)^{2N} = 2^{2N}V^{2N}$ (oh I see, I put a wrong power of 2, weird blooper, it doesn't affect the results). For large N, the log(N) part is subextensive, meaning the _entropy per particle_ vanishes. It is traditional to ignore subextensive entropy for thermodynamics, although in modern Jaynes style statistical mechanics, you include it, but keep in mind it is small.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Please think more deeply. There are always a countless number of local pressure differences anywhere inside the gas. By you and Ron these produce irreversible heat flows. Each such flow increases the total entropy of the gas. That means the entropy is constantly increasing. This is nonsense.

Comment: @Martin: You are talking about tiny pressure fluctuations in equilibrium, which are just like density fluctuations or any other fluctuation. Standardly, people say these fluctuations take the entropy temporarily down a little, then up a little as they unwind, but this is pre-information-theory. If you learn that the density/pressure fluctuation happened, then the gas entropy went down. The moment the pressure/density equals out, the density went up. The concept of "entropy" doesn't work if you can follow the details of each molecule at every single instant in time.

Comment: @Ron: Thanks for your great answer. This really helped me a lot. Thanks to you, I am looking forward to our statistical physics lecture. (before now, I was rather conservative since it all seemed to be a bit hand-waving and subjective). What a pity that I'll have to wait for the fifth semester to come ;-)

Comment: @Ron: I still do not agree with you. Another problem with your answer is that an external observer is not able to determine whether or not the change of entropy.  There is no heat exchange with the external environment and the gas performs no work. If the observer cannot determine, is there the change in entropy, then does it make sense to talk about the change in entropy?

Comment: @Martin: If you have a gas on the left, and vacuum on the right, and you lift the wall, you have no work done, and no heat flow. But the system's entropy goes up. The observer can measure the pressures before and after--- this is a macroscopic system, and this measurement has a negligible effect on it--- and see that they equalized. All this is elementary, and is covered in any statistical physics book.

Comment: @Martin: when the pressure difference disappears the entropy does not go up! I calculated the entropy change, and it is positive when there is a pressure difference, and zero when there is no pressure difference. The tiny nonextensive entropy gain when the numbers are _exactly_ equal is too small to bother with, and is never realized in a real system. In a real system you don't know the numbers are equal, only the average pressures are equal. In such a situation, the entropy stays constant when you lift the wall.

Comment: @Ron: Yes, i think that when the pressure difference disappears the entropy does not go up, automatically.  
I use the definition of the entropy:  $\Delta S=\int  \frac{\delta Q}{T}$. This follows directly from that. I think that your approach takes into account possibilities which are not applicable for ideal gas. For example the situations where greater amount of gas is collected into one part of the container and there is few molecules in another part and like. The gas must be more or less continuously distributed in a container.

Comment: @Martin: The formula $\Delta S = {\int \delta Q\over T}$ is _only_ true for reversible processes. You can't use it for irreversible processes, it is incorrect.

Comment: @Ron: Yes, but what we need is the entropy difference in the two equilibrium states. We can choose some reversible processes and  bring the gas from initial state to final state reversibly. And then calculate the entropy change by mentioned formula.

Comment: @Martin: and this is what the OP did, and he got his _nonzero_ answer (for different pressures), and this agrees with my answer in the thermodynamic limit, and it gives an entropy gain whenever the density is different on different sides. Where is the trouble??

Comment: @Ron: OP calculated only 2 different gases case.

Comment: @Gales: But the answer for two same gasses is almost exactly the same, it just omits the entropy of mixing, as he suggested in the post. The same-gas problem heat flows are the same as the different gas problem heat flows, except if you use a semi-permeable membrane as your piston.

Comment: @Ron: +1 You are right, of course! I finally got to understand where I was wrong. Sorry about the mess. The discussion was very fruitful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin: No problem, I'm sure it will be helpful to someone else who stumbles on this.